# Django: A None DateInput does not pass through form validate. How can I fix it?

Tags: django, django-forms

I use `UpdateView` and created a field called `date_updated`. When the user creates, e.g., a Group, there are zero updates. In `models.py` I defined:

```
date_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Then in `forms.py` I created the update form, e.g.,

```
class UpdateGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['name','date_updated']
```

In templates I call my form, as expected  in the iteration  `{% for field in form %}`,
`field.value = None` for the specific field `date_updated`, and because of this I believe is not updating. In `views.py` I have the following in the `UpdateGroup` class

```
 def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.instance.owner == self.request.user:
            form.instance.date_updated = timezone.now()
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super().form_invalid(form)
```

I tried to replace the empty value with a fake date considering in my templates the following:

```
{% if field.name == 'date_updated' and field.value == None %}
 <input type="date" name="date_updated" value="2000-01-01" format="yyyy-mm-dd" required disabled>                      
{% else %}
```

But it doesn't work also, I cannot validate the form and update my values with the first update.. What can I do? The only thing that works is to remove `date_updated` from `forms.py`, do the first update and then restore it in `forms.py`. Now because is not an empty Date everything works and I can proceed with a second update....so the first update is where I'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the field `date_updated` from your form and template since you want it to be `timezone.now()`. This way you wont have to set a value for it like None. You should just keep this part `form.instance.date_updated = timezone.now()` which will do what you wanted.

Comment: Perfect!!! to call `date_updated` I used the general model, e.g., `group.date_updated`. With that trick I was able to put it in `templates` without being called by the form submit button. Thanks for the advice..is a trick however, not a clean result.

Comment: If you want it to be shown in the template, you can include it in the form and just disable it using a widget so one cannot edit it since you are updating it during validation. That way you wont have to use the model and it wont be tricky.